# When does pygame.init() ever return something other than (6,0)?

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I type `pygame.init()` in the Python shell, it always (for me) returns `(6,0)`. Is there a reason why and when does it return something other than `(6,0)`? (From the documentation I think it means the initialization was perfect since there was no fails.)

Comment: A downvote is a bit cruel ) :     poor soul keep your chin up lol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init):

```
init() -> (numpass, numfail)
```

So that would mean that 6 submodules initiated successfully, and 0 failed. There could be more submodules in the future (or less). This is just feedback from the framework that everything is hunky dory, or should be at least.